# SQL - logic behind exists and not exists in multiple dependent sub queries

Tags: sql

suppose we have three relations as the below:

- suppliers( S̲i̲d̲, sname )
- parts( P̲i̲d̲, pname )
- catalog( S̲i̲d̲, P̲i̲d̲ )

S̲i̲d̲ and P̲i̲d̲ in catalog table, are foreign keys referencing to suppliers and parts. The record (s1, p1) means that supplier s1 has produced the part p1.

### I would like one to explain the logic of the query below, in the following four cases:

```
SELECT * 
FROM parts P
WHERE ---(A)--- (SELECT S.Sid 
                FROM suppliers S
                WHERE ---(B)--- (SELECT * 
                                FROM catalog C 
                                WHERE S.Sid=C.Sid AND P.Pid=C.Pid))
```

now our cases for (A) and (B) are:

1. (A):NOT EXISTS
    (B):EXISTS

   ---
2. (A):EXISTS
    (B):EXISTS

   ---
3. (A):EXISTS
    (B):NOT EXISTS

   ---
4. (A):NOT EXISTS
    (B):NOT EXISTS

**supposing the following sample tables:**
[sample tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TffXC.png)

Many Thanks

**Below is the result of each case on the given sample tables :**
case 1 --> parts which have not produced by any of suppliers (40)
case 2 --> parts which have been produced at least by one of the suppliers (10, 20, 30)
case 3 --> parts which have not produced by some of the suppliers (20, 30, 40?)
case4 --> parts which have been produced by all of the suppliers (10)

please explain how to get them and explain the logic, step by step

Comment: which rdbms? please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've asked for it's logic, independent from any rdbms. suppose solving it in a exam

Comment: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm )     go through the given link as `exists` returns only `true or false` same is the case for `not exists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the scenario mentioned the three are queries are `dependent` on each other.

`Case 1`: If the `Lower query` returns some results then it lets middle query to get executed,similarly if the `middle query` does not returns any results then the `upper query` gets executed.

`Case 2`: If the `Lower query` returns some results then it lets middle query to get executed and if the `middle query` returns any results then the `upper query` gets executed.

`Case 3`: If the `Lower query` does not returns any results then it lets middle query to get executed and if the `middle query` returns some results it lets the `upper query` to get executed.

`Case 4`: If the `Lower query` does not returns any results then it lets middle query to get executed and if the `middle query` also does not returns any results it lets the `upper query` to get executed.

`Explaining Case 1`: `SELECT * FROM catalog C WHERE S.Sid=C.Sid AND P.Pid=C.Pid`  returns the join of all the three tables

Example:
1 ali 10 A
1 ali 30 C
.
.
if some record gets fetched through this join condition then `middle query` 
SELECT S.Sid 
                FROM suppliers S  gets executed it fetches all the sid present in suppliers table.
Since now the `middle query` is also giving some results so the `upper query` won't get executed and so data will be fetched from the whole query.

Comment: could you please, step by step go through the given query and sample tables, and find the result for at least one of the scenarios?

Comment: edited the answer with the explanation pls go throw..if you are satisfied green tick it.

Comment: thank you, but in the first scenario we would get part IDs (here Pids) which have not produced by any of suppliers , in our sample tables we gonna get Pid = 40

Comment: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions012.htm )     go through the given link as `exists` returns only `true or false` same is the case for `not exists`.

Comment: thanks, I know what exists and not exists do. But here I got confused with sub queries which are linked together and hard to deal with it without knowing overall logic